`head :no_content` is not stop
When We made RESTful API, We used :no_content for 204 http status code
But next line code of head :no_content is not stop in controller.
Then I used return code with head :no_content, but I not sure which of below code is better
1.
(head :no_content and return) if data_is_empty




return head :no_content if data_is_empty




if data_is_empty
   return head :no_content 
end


There's no "best" here, just opinions. I'd go with return head :no_content if data_is_empty though as I dislike using and and or (opinion) and I like having important things like return right up front where you can't miss it (more opinion).

None of the above.
These three don't even do the same thing:
(head :no_content and return) if data_is_empty

return head :no_content if data_is_empty

if data_is_empty
   return head :no_content 
end

The first and third returns nil and the second returns true. What they all do is halt further execution of the method they are in but not the callback chain.
In very old versions of Rails returning false from a callback or a controller action would implicitly halt the callbacks chain. Which is why you seem idioms like this legacy code:
render text: "Oh noes" and return false

But in Rails 5 that behavior changed and you should use throw(:abort) to halt further processing.
class ThingsController
  before_action :bail_hard, if: :data_is_empty?

  private

  def bail_hard
    head :no_content 
    throw(:abort)
  end
end

Throw is also a control expression in Ruby like return but it lets you break out of deeply nested constructs until an equivilent catch is found and not just the current method.
An alternative way of doing this would be to raise an exception (which also halts execution) and use rescue_from to send a response.
class NoDataException < StandardError
end

class ThingsController
  rescue_from NoDataException, with: :handle_no_data

  def some_method
    raise NoDataException if no_data? 
    # ...
  end

  private

  def handle_no_data
    head :no_content 
  end
end

This is suitible if this is an exceptional event and it lets you move the logic for handling the exception up the inheritance chain.

2nd and 3rd are equivalent. 1st is different.

@BrunoCostanzo ah you're right it's 2 & 3 that have the same return value.
